# HP Pavillon 15-ec1xxx Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation problem

Tags: boot, 20.04, uefi, lts

Yesterday I installed latest Ubuntu LTS on HP Pavillon laptop but it does not want to cooperate. After performing entire process of installation (completed with success), Ubuntu is not even loading. BIOS unfortunately is accepting only UEFI module (but with disabled 'Secure' option).  Tried as well to fix the problem with Boot-Repair executed from liveCD, but without succes. Log from the boot-repair works is available here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fdmFCkqTW9/

It says, that there is unknown bootloader on HDD. Don't know actually how to fix this and make it finally work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to disable Secure Boot. [These instructions from HP](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03736054) might help you.

Comment: OK,finally fix it :) Used advanced options via Boot-Repair with reinstalling GRUB + once again checked how BIOS was set up. The thing is, that except disabling secure boot, we need to enable option:

[code]Load HP Factory Default Keys[/code]

With that, OS Boot Manager recognizes Ubuntu. This is first thing. Second - reinstallation of GRUB with option "nomodeset". And that's it, now it works well.

Thanks!